# G'dalya Gumber provenance

Tags: song-poetry, english, provenance

There's a popular song about *G'dalya* Gumber (spelling?), who is "seventeen feet tall" and who "ain't gonna work on Saturday", not even for "double, double, triple pay". Who wrote and who published this song, and when? (Any additional information about its provenance, such as who popularized it and how, is also most welcome.)

I've Googled a bit and gotten some conflicting information, so seek an authoritative source of information.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Yess

Comment: Wasn't it 'Uncle Moishy'?

Comment: So far, I have for the song "Big Gedaliah Goomber" that it was recorded here http://shuandnat.blogspot.com/2007/02/big-gedalia-goomber.html and a comment (and album cover) points to a R. Silverman (corroborated by http://zemerl.com/cgi-bin/show.pl?title=Ain't+gonna+work+on+Saturday) but http://www.imamother.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=1757808 can be read as attributing to a R. Levinson.

Comment: @Dan, yeah, I'd Googled a bit, but found nothing definite.

Comment: I assumed it was Goomberg.

Comment: [More discussion about this question.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468/2013/2/6)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Mishpacha magazine, issue 455, 7 Iyar 5773, (April 17, 2013), Mrs. Blima Silverman of Toronto, Ontario, writes (in a letter to the editor), "In your February 20 edition the song, 'Big Gedalia Goomber' was attributed to yet another person who did not write it." She writes further, "The song (both music and lyrics) was composed by my husband, Rabbi Yosaif Silverman z"l, in the early '60s, as anyone attending Telshe Yeshiva at that time can attest. The record was produced in 1969, along with other tunes he had written, and is still under copyright."

Comment: R. G., thank you for the information, and welcome to Mi Yodeya. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 3):

[this site](http://zemerl.com/cgi-bin/show.pl?title=Ain%27t%20gonna%20work%20on%20Saturday) says it was Rabbi Silverman

Comment: Does Rabbi Silverman have a first name? There are probably a lot of Rabbi Silvermans out there.

Comment: Please see my recent edit to the question.

Comment: @PM Yosaif Silverman as per the album cover http://shuandnat.blogspot.com/2007/02/big-gedalia-goomber.html

Comment: "Eh, maybe a little." Ep. 4F22

Comment: @Dan, looks like an answer. Or an edit to this one. Anyway, it's the best evidence thus far posted.

Answer (score -2):

Uncle Moishy and his Mitvah men

see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncle_Moishy_and_the_Mitzvah_Men) about him:

Here is [another link](http://instalyrics.com/artists/89185-uncle-moishy/lyrics/2578291-new-gedaliah-goomber) which shows that it's him

Comment: That site says that Uncle Moishy sang it and put new lyrics to it, but not that he was the first to sing it. I suspect the song predates his act by many years. Please also see my recent edit to the question.