# Source for song "Don't walk in front of me"

Tags: song-poetry, music

A popular Jewish children's song contains the lyrics

> Don't walk in front of me, I may not follow; Don't walk behind me, I may not lead; Just walk beside me, and just be my friend.

This is actually a [quote from Albert Camus](http://quotationsbook.com/quote/15990/) I would like to know when and how this became part of the Jewish song.

Comment: http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/uncle-moishy-stole-the-quote

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8826/being-a-light-to-the-nations-what-does-it-mean#comment11437_8833

Comment: similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22180/759

Comment: It could be the attribution to Camus is incorrect. See here: http://blog.quotesome.com/10-famous-misquotations-and-misattributed-quotes/ and here:http://darrananderson.com/2013/05/25/albert-camus-and-the-ventriloquists/

Comment: This is almost certainly not from Albert Camus. But Uncle Moishe is still around, perhaps someone will ask him one day ...

Comment: it does not even appear to be from camus according to the different sites that investigated this question.
the original author seems to still be unknown

Answer (score 11):

This first appeared in a Jewish context with the release of *[Uncle Moishy and the Mitzvah Men vol. 2](http://mostlymusic.com/products/uncle-moishy-vol-2)*, in the early 1980s.

> Don't walk in front of me, I may not follow;
>   Don't walk behind me, I may not lead;
>   Just walk beside me, and be my friend;
>   And together we will walk in the way of Hashem.